# Spring Batch Tomcat memory leak

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-boot, spring-batch

I use

```
Tomcat 8.0.26
Spring Boot 1.2.6.RELEASE
Spring 4.2.1.RELEASE
Spring Batch 3.0.5.RELEASE
```

In my application I have a following Spring Batch config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class ReportJobConfig {

    public static final String REPORT_JOB_NAME = "reportJob";

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private ReportService reportService;

    @Bean(name = REPORT_JOB_NAME)
    public Job reportJob() {
        //@formatter:off
        return jobBuilderFactory
                .get(REPORT_JOB_NAME)
                    .flow(createRequestStep())
                        .on("*").to(retriveInfoStep())
                            .on("*").to(notifyAdminStep())
                    .end().build();
        //@formatter:on
    }

    @Bean
    public Step createRequestStep() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("createRequest").tasklet(new CreateRequestTasklet(reportService)).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step retrivePHIStep() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("retriveInfo").tasklet(new RetriveInfoTasklet(reportService)).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step notifyAdminStep() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("notifyAdmin").tasklet(new NotifyAdminTasklet()).build();
    }

}
```

This is how I run the job:

```
@Service
public class ReportJobServiceImpl implements ReportJobService {

    final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ReportJobServiceImpl.class);

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(ReportJobConfig.REPORT_JOB_NAME)
    private Job reportJob;

    @Autowired
    private JobLauncher jobLauncher;

    @Override
    public void runReportJob(String messageContent) throws JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException, JobRestartException,
            JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException, JobParametersInvalidException {
        Map<String, JobParameter> parameters = new HashMap<>();
        JobParameter reportIdParameter = new JobParameter(messageContent);
        parameters.put(REPORT_ID, reportIdParameter);

        jobLauncher.run(reportJob, new JobParameters(parameters));
    }

}
```

Batch properties:

```
batch.jdbc.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
batch.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/database
batch.jdbc.user=user
batch.jdbc.password=password
batch.jdbc.testWhileIdle=true
batch.jdbc.validationQuery=SELECT 1
batch.drop.script=classpath:/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-drop-mysql.sql
batch.schema.script=classpath:/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-mysql.sql
batch.business.schema.script=classpath:/business-schema-mysql.sql
batch.database.incrementer.class=org.springframework.jdbc.support.incrementer.MySQLMaxValueIncrementer
batch.database.incrementer.parent=columnIncrementerParent
batch.lob.handler.class=org.springframework.jdbc.support.lob.DefaultLobHandler
batch.grid.size=50
batch.jdbc.pool.size=6
batch.verify.cursor.position=true
batch.isolationlevel=ISOLATION_SERIALIZABLE
batch.table.prefix=BATCH_
```

I deploy this application to Tomcat 8, perform some jobs and then undeploy application via Tomcat Web Application Manager.

With Java VisualVM tool I compared memory snapshots before and after and see that there are a lot of Spring Batch(`org.springframework.batch.*`) related objects still exist in memory:

[image]

Also, I run 1000 `reportJob` and got a huge memory consumption on my machine.. I have no idea what can be wrong right now..

What could be causing this issue ?

**UPDATED**

I have consumed ~1000 messages from AWS SQS queue. My JMS listener configured to consume 1 message at a time. During the execution I had a following heap histogram:

[image]

I really don't understand why do I need for example to have in memory 7932 instances of StepExecution.. or 5285 of JobExecution objects. Where is my mistake ?

Comment: Just because it's a long list...that list you show isn't eating up an real large chunk of memory (all the references are small and not very numerous).  We need more information on what's eating up the memory.

Comment: Michael, thanks for your answer. I have updated my question and added new profiler snapshot of allocating `org.springframework.batch.*` objects during the executing of Batch jobs for 1000 messages from AWS SQS queue. My JMS listener configured to consume 1 message at a time.

Comment: Where is JMS in your configuration?

Comment: I have described my JMS configuration in a separate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32865947/tomcat-8-spring-jms-aws-sqs-memory-leak

Comment: Do you have any idea where a mistake in my code can take a place?

Comment: My hunch is that you're running the job for each message instead of reading each message as part of the same job.  I'd also need more insight into what's being put in the `ExecutionContext`...it's typically pretty small.

Comment: Inside of my JMS listener I'm invoking following code `jobLauncher.run(reportJob, new JobParameters(parameters));` for an each message in the SQS queue. According to my logic, each message must go through the flow job with a many steps and deciders(~10) How to reduce the number of running jobs ? To the job parameters I'm adding simple String and that's all right now.

Comment: Why are you not using a JMSItemReader that reads the messages from the queue?  What does the JMS message contain and how does it relate to your job?

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea how to use JMSItemReader with AWS SQS queue.. My JMS message contains JSON object with a few properties. In my Batch Job I have described a flow(different steps and deciders) for how to proceed with a data in these SQS messages based on different conditions and application state.

Comment: Is it possible to use JmsItemReader with a Batch Flow job ? If so, could you please provide an example ?

Comment: What's wrong to start a new flow job in JMS listener when a message appears ?

Comment: I need to continuously listen queue for new text messages.. thousands of messages. When a new message appears, I need to start a job with a flow of steps and deciders. Is Spring Batch suitable for such kind of task or I need to remove it from my project ?